# ArrayList difficulty in add() method

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program which creates an `ArrayList` of Buttons in a `JFrame` row by row. But I am having a problem at `Line 21` and `Line 22`.
For `Line 21`, I am getting an error telling that it cannot find any `setBounds()` method. But isn't it one of the methods of the `JButton`? 
In `Line 22` the error is

> no suitable method found for add(Object)

But didn't I mention that it is an `ArrayList` holding `JButton`'s in `Line 16`?
Any detailed explanation could be helpful.

```
package Buttonrows;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Buttonrows extends JFrame {
public ArrayList buttons;


public Buttonrows(){
ArrayList<JButton>buttons=new ArrayList<JButton>(); //Line 16
buttons.add(new JButton("Apple"));
buttons.add(new JButton("Banana"));
buttons.add(new JButton("Grapes"));
buttons.add(new JButton("Mango"));
buttons.add(new JButton("Pineapple"));
for(int i=0;i<=buttons.size()-1;i++){
    buttons.get(i).setBounds(30,i*60,100,50); //Line 21
    add(buttons.get(i));                      //Line 22
}
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(800,800);
setLayout(null);
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
Buttonrows program=new Buttonrows();        
 }
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using and what is the JDK settings? Note that at the end of your constructor the raw `ArrayList` for the `Buttonrow` instances is shadowed by the `ArrayList` you create in the constructor.

Comment: I use NetBeans IDE, But I don't know how to check the JDK settings.

Comment: Works for me in NetBeans 8.1 with JDK 1.8.0_102.

Comment: But Mine is also the same version, I think version has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Cross check your project config again. It must be something wrong there, most of us are able to compile and run this code without any issue.

Comment: Works with JDK1.8.0_45. Which JDK version are you using? Have you tried making it `public ArrayList<JButton> buttons;` instead?

Comment: Also, try clean and build your project again.

Comment: @Linus    Oh, yes. A simple mistake by me. Thank you for pointing out the  mistake.

Comment: @S.Srihari, I'm glad but it works for me without doing that, so I suspect there is still an IDE setting or version issue somewhere. Best of luck.

Comment: i have netbeans 8.1 and JDK 1.8.0_77

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
((JButton)buttons.get(i)).setBounds(30,i*60,100,50);
```

and

```
add((JButton)buttons.get(i));
```

Comment: But why is this necessary?

Comment: Don't exactly know, but it seems that `buttons.get(i)` returns `Object`, not `JButton`.

Comment: But I mentioned that the `ArrayList` should hold `JButton` in Line 16, right?

Comment: I just run your program and it I don't get any error. Is the error you posted a compile or a runtime error?

Comment: I think this has to do with type erasure.  At runtime, the actual `ArrayList` holds objects, not `JButton`.  Hence the need for the cast.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok, at first sight it's kind of obvious, what the solution is. But if I think twice, there really is no need for casting (which is proven by running that code without error). It's like an older version of Java is used. For example: Java 1.4 `ArrayList` method `get(i)` returns `Object`, but back then there were also no generics supported...

Comment: @S.Srihari What's your Java version?

Comment: @peterremec By the way, for your question, it is a compile error.

Comment: @peterremec When I tried your solution, But the first cast didn't work. It shows a compilation error that it is not a proper statement

Comment: @S.Srihari edited my answer. Sorry, my mistake. Even if that works, someone should explain why is casting necessary - it's not understandable for me, too.

Comment: fixed it! A simple mistake! Instead of `public ArrayList buttons`, I tried it as `public ArrayList<JButton> buttons`. It fixed the issue.

Comment: @S.Srihari that makes sense, I totally missed the `public ArrayList buttons;` part. But one thing i don't understand: Why do you have a new (local) variable with the same name (`buttons`) in a constructor? Probably you'd like to use class variable to store `Jbutton`'s, right?